# Unable to compile through command prompt

Tags: java

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;

class Reading{

    public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception {
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        int intNumber = 0;
        float floatNumber = 0.0f;

        System.out.println("Enter integer and float number");

        intNumber = Integer.parseInt(din.readLine());
        floatNumber = Float.valueOf(din.readLine()).floatValue();

        System.out.println("Integer" + intNumber);
        System.out.println("Float" + floatNumber);
    }
}

/* Output

Note: Reading.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

*/
```

Comment: As you can see, compiler has given you the option to compile in a different way to know the exact reason. So you can trust the compiler and try it..

Comment: This is only a warning. The method `readLine` in `DataInputStream` is deprecated, as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()).

Comment: Have you tried to run this code, because despite that warning about deprecated API (`readLine()` method) it seams to work fine for me?

Comment: Tried compiling using '-Xlint:deprecation'.. Gives me too warnings.. Other than that works fine.. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You are actually compiling fine. The output contains some warnings as you seems to use some deprecated APIs.

Answer (score 0):

`DataInputStream.readLine()` is `deprecated` method. **It will work fine for now** but recommended to use some Reader stream(`BufferedReader`) to read the date.

Answer (score 0):

The `din.readLine()` is deprecate, you can use `javac -Xlint YouClass.java` for see the error in the next time.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a warning you can still get your output

for details about deprecated Api refer to

[Deprecated Api Details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/deprecation/deprecation.html)